# Nodejs Express outsource logic from controller to service

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

i have a function that gets data from an API. I now want to outsource the program logic to a service to keep the controller cleaner.

I get the data about Async/Await, unfortunately I don't know how to outsource it to a service?

Anyone have an idea?

Here my homeController.js:

```js
const ispwrapper = require('../lib/ispwrapper');
require('dotenv').config();


const BASE_URL = process.env.API_BASE_URL;

const OPTIONS = {
    username: process.env.API_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.API_PASSWORD
};

const renderHome = async (req, res) => {
    let domain = [],
        message = '';
    try {
        let a = new ispwrapper.ISPConfig(BASE_URL, OPTIONS);
        const response = await a.getDataByPrimaryId('sites_web_domain_get', { active: 'y' });

        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
            domain.push(response[i].domain);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        message = 'Error when retriving domains from API';
    } finally {
        res.render('home', {
            title: 'ISPConfig',
            heading: 'Welcome to my ISPConfig Dashboard',
            homeActive: true,
            domain,
            message
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    renderHome
};
```

My homeService.js:

```js
const
    ispwrapper = require('../lib/ispwrapper');
require('dotenv').config();

const BASE_URL = process.env.API_BASE_URL;

const OPTIONS = {
    username: process.env.API_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.API_PASSWORD
};

const getDomains = async () => {

// i have no idea how use my renderHome() logic here
};
module.exports = {
    getDomains
};
```

Comment: Just put those parts of the function that don't involve `res` in the `getDomains` function?

Comment: But we handle try catch finally?

Comment: Either keep it in the controller, or have `getDomains` return an object containing domains and message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution.

domainService.js:

```js
const
    ispwrapper = require('../lib/ispwrapper');
require('dotenv').config();

const BASE_URL = process.env.API_BASE_URL;

const OPTIONS = {
    username: process.env.API_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.API_PASSWORD
};

const getDomains = async () => {
    let data = [];
    try {
        let a = new ispwrapper.ISPConfig(BASE_URL, OPTIONS);
        let response = await a.getDataByPrimaryId('sites_web_domain_get', { active: 'y' });

        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
            data.push(response[i].domain);
        }
        return data;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    getDomains
};
```

homeController:

```js
const homeService = require('../services/domainService');

const renderHome = async (req, res) => {
    let message = '',
        domain = [];
    try {
        let response = await homeService.getDomains();

        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
            domain.push(response[i]);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        message = 'Error when retriving domains from API';
    } finally {
        res.render('home', {
            title: 'ISPConfig',
            heading: 'Welcome to my ISPConfig Dashboard',
            homeActive: true,
            domain,
            message
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    renderHome
};
```